# How to show results from database splited on the columns in django

Tags: django

I have a question about how to show list of records from db splitted on for example 3 columns. I tried to wrote this :

```
{% for wpis in wpisy_kat %}
<a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=wpis.slug_kat %}">{{ wpis|slice:"1:5" }} </a> ({{ wpis.cnt_witryna }}) <br />
{% endfor %}
```

but on the end I still have full list (in my case 56 records).

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to split up this list into two columns of data?   If so, I would suggest you look at django's forloop divisible by feature which will allow you to do this.

```
{% for wpis in wpisy_kat %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}
        <a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=wpis.slug_kat %}">{{ 
        wpis|slice:"1:5" }} </a> ({{ wpis.cnt_witryna }}) <br />
    {% else %}
        <a href="{% url 'detale_kat' slug_kat=wpis.slug_kat %}">{{ 
        wpis|slice:"1:5" }} </a> ({{ wpis.cnt_witryna }}) <br />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and nothing was changed. Only when i refresh website the html display me {{wpis|slice:"1:5"}} instead origin name of category